# jQuery Mobile navbar navigation

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, navbar

I'm developing my first app using jQuery Mobile and I got a question (didn't find anything in the web). I'm using a navbar with 3 pages.

The first page shows some Wikipedia stuff inside an `iframe` (keep it in mind)!
When I click on the second page (Approfondimenti), it shows a vertical menu with some elements that I can click.

What my jQuery function does (by clicking on one of the menu element in the second page) is to change the iframe 'src' to a new URL... but I don't know how to go back to the first page with my function so my app could show the URL change (don't want manual click on the first page to load `iframe` content).

Can you help me?

Here is my function:

```
$(document).on('click', '.a', function(e){ // here i already am in the second page
       var appr=$(this).attr('id'); //here i get the URL from second page, i stored them in the elements id
   $('#iframe').attr('src',appr); //here i set new URL 
       //HERE WHAT TO DO????????
    });
```

[image]

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '.a', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); rest of your code });` if I get what you need.

Comment: no, i don't want to prevent action about the elements in the second page, cause they are just <li>. when i click them, my function is triggered so it change the URL iframe (in page "Foro"). Then i want to go back (or to switch if you like it) to the "Foro" page without clicking it, i want to automate this action directly in my function using some methods.

Comment: Can you put this in jsfiddle.net because I still can't get what you mean.

Comment: Here it is! http://jsfiddle.net/manhunt/q2LJX/5/
Just click on "Approfondimenti" and select one item, my function is triggered as it changes iframe URL, but you can see the result only if you click on "Foro" page, i want to automate this in my function.

Comment: `$('.a').on('click', function` since `.a` links are not dynamically added.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q2LJX/11/

Comment: @alfa - use `vclick` rather than `click` in jQuery Mobile apps - It will work better on touch capable mobile devices. `click` works best in environments with a mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to change page in jQuery mobile:

```
 $.mobile.changePage("#page1");
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/androdify/q2LJX/9/

Comment: Oh, it works on jsfiddle but not on my browser (desktop). Is it normal?

Comment: @alfa it should work on desktop too, probably some other error